# Can operations, which assign values to multiple volatile fields consecutively, be reordered?

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, volatile, java-memory-model

Will the following code always print-out the "correct" value of **data**? Even if there are other operations between assigning the values to **data** and **dataReady** in method **setData**?

Or could the JVM conceivably re-order these operations such that **RunningThread** could see **dataReady** as true whilst **data** were still null?

If the code is safe & correct- what is it about a volatile field that prevents re-ordering problems? Does this mean that **data** itself doesn't even need to be volatile, that there is something about making just **dataReady** volatile which causes the JVM to not cache local values for other fields of an instance where one field is volatile?

```
public class RunningThread implements Runnable {

private volatile boolean dataReady = false;
private volatile String data = null;

public void run() {
    while (!dataReady){
        //Do stuff or wait
    }
    System.out.println("Value of data '" +data +"' is definitely not null.");
}


//setData called by another thread
public void setData(String dataToSet){
    if (dataToSet!=null){
        data = dataToSet;
        dataReady = true;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All writes performed by a thread before writing to a `volatile` variable will be visible to another thread after reading the value from the `volatile` variable which the former thread has written.

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5)’s wording is:

> If *x* and *y* are actions of the same thread and *x* comes before *y* in program order, then *hb(x, y)*.
>
> …
>
> If *hb(x, y)* and *hb(y, z)*, then *hb(x, z)*.
>
> …
>
> A write to a `volatile` field ([§8.3.1.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4)) *happens-before* every subsequent read of that field.

So the write to `data` *happens-before* the same thread writes to `dataReady` which *happens-before* a second thread reads `dataReady` which *happens-before* the second thread reads `data`.

In other words, the memory visibility guarantees regarding the `dataReady` variable are enough to guard to read of `data`, it isn’t even necessary to declare `data` as `volatile`.

Comment: Wouldn't `data` be thread-safe even without marking it as `volatile` and without the use a `dataReady` flag? (since String is immutable)

Comment: @Chetan Kinger: well, if `data` is `volatile` and the reader checks against `null`, you wouldn’t need another flag, but I suppose that this is just a simplified example. If `data` is not `volatile` you will still never see corrupt values as `String` is immutable, but without the `volatile` flag you have no guarantees to see the most recent values, thus a polling thread could end up in an infinite loop seeing always `null`.